# Drupal clean URLs not working from subdirectory

Tags: redirection, uri

I'm not sure if this belongs here or in serverfault, so feel free to flag it if necessary. I have a server with a drupal installation at /drupal. I want the URL www.example.com to point to www.example.com/drupal. I don't want to change my server root, just do an Apache Rewrite.

```
RewriteRule (.*) /drupal/$1
```

This works, so when I type www.example.com I go to the drupal site. The issue is no other URLs go to the correct spot. So when I type a URL like www.example.com/about, I see the drupal theme but then the content just says

> The requested page "/about" could not be found.

The page www.example.com/drupal/about does show up fine. I've also changed $base_url to www.example.com. Any idea what could be wrong?

I've also tested that URLs like www.example.com/?q=node/16 work fine, so the problem is just with clean URLs.

Answer (score 2):

Problem in drupal Clean URL, To Enable drupal clean url in subdirectory un comment the following line in .htaccess file.

```
  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  RewriteBase /
```

for more refer the blog [Enable drupal clean url in subdirectory or subdomain](http://blog.innovsystems.com/drupal/enable-drupal-clean-url-subdirectory-or-subdomain)

Comment: I've uncommented that line and restarted the apache server but the issue is still there. But you're right that the problem is with clean urls, I've tested that URLs like /?q=node/16 work fine.

Comment: Solution to use virtual hosts http://drupal.org/node/111238